# IntelliJ IDEA editor does not open my XML layout files

Tags: android, intellij-idea, designer

I tried finding a similar topic, but could not find one.

IntelliJ IDEA crashed (along with my PC) and when I got it back and running, I saw that I can not preview any XML files. I could before the crash, of course.

All I get is what you can see in the screenshot : I can not even chose target API, none of the options do anything, and I tried stretching the view, but nothing happens.

Here's the screenshot :

http://tinypic.com/r/10ct1g3/9

The error I got was :

> Exception in plugin Android Support. 5 minutes ago. Occured once since the last clear. Unread.
>
> Error message :
> null

I really don't have a clue what to do.

Comment: Reinstall from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html, delete [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519).

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue than normally it already helps if you click Build -> Clean Project and then Build -> Rebuild Project.

After that it should work. If during that process an error message pops up then that is the reason why the preview doesn't work.

Comment: It didn't work. I had to uninstall the program and that was it.